# PHP array, substitute the key within a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have read a lot of posts and have not been able to find a solution to my issue.

I have a `$_POST` array named "Water", `$_POST['Water']` and its contents are:

```
 [Water] => Array ( [0] => 55.0 [1] => 22 )
```

Is it possible to use the name of the post inside a foreach loop so the `$key` could use the name "Water":

```
foreach($_POST['Water']  as $key => $val) {
    $fields[] = "$field = '$val'";
    //echo "Key: $key, Value: $val<br/>\n";
}
```

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: so do you want to use values as keys? That's what you are asking here?

Comment: @Jay Patel , no I am use the values already. What I am trying to do is use the $_POST name "Water" so the key would look like "Water[0] and "Water[1].

Comment: Try  `$fields['Water'][$key] = $val;` or `$fields['Water'.$key] = $val;`

Comment: you can use two-dimensional array if it is possible for you for your particular problem. In that way it will be like `['Water'][0]`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. `foreach()` operates on the contents of an array. Whatever actually contains that array is outside of foreach's view. If you want to dynamically use the `Water` key elsewhere, you'll have to do that yourself:

```
$key = 'Water'
foreach($_POST[$key] as $val) {
   $fields[] = "$key = '$val'";
}
```

Comment: prefect. many thanks to you all for looking at the issue. Marc B has it working.

Answer (score 0):

If I read this right you basically want `$field='water'` inside the `foreach`. This can be done be rethinking the way we build the `foreach`.

You simply need to make the field value a variable and pass use that rather everywhere the value is needed.

```
$field = 'Water';
foreach($_POST[$field]  as $key => $val) {
    $fields[] = "$field = '$val'";
    //echo "Key: $key, Value: $val<br/>\n";
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that if you change your mind and the $_POST key is later called, "liquid" one single line needs to be edited and that is all. Furthermore, if your `foreach` were part of a function $field could be a function parameter. In a roundabout way, you are actually getting pretty close to some code reuse principles.